# Get likes from facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to build a small function where I retrieve the likes of a certain page on Facebook.

My script looks like

```
$.getJSON('https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.example.com&format=json',function(data) {
                   currentdiv.text((data.like_count || 0)+'');
                   console.log(data.like_count);
                });
```

However, `like_count` returns undefined.

The data I get back from Facebook is:

```
[{"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com","normalized_url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/","share_count":19,"like_count":55,"comment_count":40,"total_count":114,"click_count":0,"comments_fbid":10150397389269673,"commentsbox_count":0}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON response is data of object, so Use this: `data[0].like_count`

```
$.getJSON('https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.naturalpotential.dk&format=json',function(data) {
                   //currentdiv.text((data.like_count || 0)+'');
                   console.log(data[0].like_count);
                });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/54d51c85/)

Comment: Most Welcome @nickycdk. Enjoy Scripting

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you get back returns an array containing the object.

This should work:

```
Console.log(data[0].like_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you are getting back is an array containing an object with a `like_count` property.

You are trying to read the `like_count` property from the array (where one doesn't exist).

You need to get the object first.

Answer (score 0):

You can object which having index so you have to mention index then you can able to get the like count.

```
console.log(data[0].like_count);
```